# sql php confuse complex

Tags: php, sql, date

PHP code (relevant)

> $db = '2011-02-28'; $a = '2011-02-01';

and this is the part of the query

```
    LEFT JOIN
        abc
    ON
        abc.date between '$a' and '$db'
```

This query show following results :

```
1 2011-02-08
6 2011-02-09
6 2011-02-11
1 2011-02-13
```

but what i want is to get 0 as a result if there's n rows for other dates.

Comment: Tangential comment: There is no date 2011-02-30. February only has 28 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that (not without joining a table containing all dates, at least).

Displaying the 0s for dates with no data is the job of your application, not the database. It's trivial, just write a loop from the start date to the end date, and output the 0 for those dates with no rows in your result set.

SQL's job is to tell you what data is there, not what isn't.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results[$row['date']] = $row['count'];
}

for ($time = strtotime('2011-02-01'); $time <= strtotime('2011-02-28'); $time += 86400) {
    $datestr = date('Y-m-d', $time);
    if (isset($results[$datestr])) {
        echo "Count for date $datestr: " . $results[$datestr];
    } else {
        echo "Count for date $datestr: 0";
    }
}
```

Comment: A loop from the start date to the end date, incrementing in one day intervals: `for ($date = strtotime('2011-02-01'); $date <= strtotime('2011-02-28'); $date += 86400) {`

Comment: I added a larger example to the answer.

Comment: i tried removing $datestr = date('Y-m-d', $time) but it showed no data then ?

Comment: `echo` is the PHP command that produces output. That's what you change to modify the output.

Comment: but is this $datestr = date('Y-m-d', $time) necessory?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's the date in Y-m-d form to connect the loop to the rows in your result set...

Comment: can i use php code for current month here? strtotime('2011- HERE -01');  ??

Comment: Yes you can. Please go to http://www.php.net and look up the date and time functions. This is not a discussion forum, you have to do the basics yourself.

Comment: thanks! was trying to do this since 5 days! thanks for hwlping ,its working :)

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information you give about what problem you are trying to solve I would guess you are trying to find "free appointments" or similar.

If so then this should help you out. http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#98

This website has a number of query patterns that will help your thinking and design of your database.